# Control values overridden by storyboard setting

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, controls

I have a VC of custom type `LVSBBSettingsViewController` for user settings. The VC is presented by a main menu in `LVSMainViewController`. The main VC sets the values of the controls in the settings VC programatically. However, when the settings view appears, the controls all revert to the values assigned to them in the storyboard.

I am using delegation to close the settings view and to pass data from the settings VC back to the main VC when it closes. But I don't think that's what's causing the problem since the same thing happens even if I remove that.

What's causing this? I have a feeling I'm missing something really simple here...

**LVSBBSettingsViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class LVSBBSettingsViewController;

#pragma mark LVSBBSettingsViewController Delegate

@protocol LVSBBSettingsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)settingsViewControllerDidCancel:(LVSBBSettingsViewController *)controller;
- (void)settingsViewControllerDidSave:(LVSBBSettingsViewController *)controller;

@end

#pragma mark LVSBBSettingsViewController

@interface LVSBBSettingsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LVSBBSettingsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *showBranchVarLabelsSwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *useAnimationSwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *showAllNodesSwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tempLabel;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

**LVSBBSettingsViewController.m:**

```
#import "LVSBBSettingsViewController.h"

@interface LVSBBSettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation LVSBBSettingsViewController

// ... Xcode-generated stuff ...

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate settingsViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate settingsViewControllerDidSave:self];
}

@end
```

**LVSBBMainViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "LVSBBSettingsViewController.h"

@interface LVSMainViewController : UIViewController <LVSBBSettingsViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**LVSBBMainViewController.m:**

```
#import "LVSMainViewController.h"
#import "LVSBBMasterViewController.h"

@interface LVSMainViewController ()

@end

@implementation LVSMainViewController
{
    LVSBBMasterViewController *bbmvc;
}

// ... 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get main storyboard
    UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    // Instantiate bbmvc
    bbmvc = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BBMasterViewControllerStoryboard"];

    // Initialize settings
    bbmvc.showBranchVarLabels = YES;
    bbmvc.useAnimation = YES;
    bbmvc.showAllNodes =  NO;
}

...

#pragma mark LVSBBSettingsViewController Delegate

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSettings"])
    {
        // Get pointer to settings VC
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        LVSBBSettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];

        // Set delegate
        settingsViewController.delegate = self;

        // Populate settings VC
        // (same problem occurs if I replace right-hand sides of next 3 lines with NO;)
        settingsViewController.showBranchVarLabelsSwitch.on = bbmvc.showBranchVarLabels;
        settingsViewController.useAnimationSwitch.on = bbmvc.useAnimation;
        settingsViewController.showAllNodesSwitch.on = bbmvc.showAllNodes;
        settingsViewController.tempLabel.text = @"HELLO";
    }
}

- (void)settingsViewControllerDidCancel:(LVSBBSettingsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)settingsViewControllerDidSave:(LVSBBSettingsViewController *)controller
{
    // Set settings in bbmvc
    bbmvc.showBranchVarLabels = controller.showBranchVarLabelsSwitch.on;
    bbmvc.useAnimation = controller.useAnimationSwitch.on;
    bbmvc.showAllNodes = controller.showAllNodesSwitch.on;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

**UPDATE:** As a workaround, I added properties in `LVSBBSettingsViewController` that match the properties in `LVSMainViewController`. In `prepareForSegue:sender:`, I set those properties instead of setting the controls directly. Then in `viewDidLoad` in `LVSBBSettingsViewController`, I set the control values based on the properties. This seems to work. Still not sure why I can't set the control values directly, though.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint when you set the values of the settings controller to see if it ever gets called.

Comment: Already done -- yes, it gets called.